# Newman run overfilling cache memory

Tags: bash, postman, newman

I have a problem with overfilling cache memory, using long newman runs. I run collection which adds some data to my database in live mode. It shouldnt stop but when its working about 2 hours, cache memory is filled and my computer stops working properly.

My computer has 8 GB RAM but its not enough.
[image]

Durning run, free cache memory is dropping. Old data (which is useless for me) is kept and released too slow which causes overfilling cache memory. 
I am not a root and cant use this command:
 # sync; echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches

Have can I cope with this and dont keep this data in cache?
Thanks for any kind of help.

Comment: I removed the [cpu-cache] tag because this question is not about the cache as used in the CPU. Actually, I'm not even sure what OS you are using: it seems Linux but the screenshot looks like Windows Task manager. BTW the `buff/cache` value is quite low, it's not a problem with the page cache (and if it was, Linux would handle it for you). You probably just need to free up some references on your scala code, the OS cannot help you here.

Comment: I use ubuntu for windows 10